# How do I connect to Ubuntu One after changing the password?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I changed my password for Ubuntu One using the Web interface, and added a new computer. Since then, the old computer does not synchronize with Ubuntu One. It doesn't show any error messages or such, but files uploaded from the web interface or changed on the newly added computer don't appear/change on the old computer. I guess that it can't connect because it is still using the old password.

The problem is that I can't find an interface to change the password the client is using to connect to the service. The "manage account" option opens the Web interface. I looked into the keyring, and found the key for Ubuntu One, but there I only see an encrypted version of the password, so I can't change it there.

So what is the correct way to tell my client that my account password has changed?

**Edit** this is what I see when I open Preferences --> Ubuntu One. Is there something wrong with it? It also stubbornly insists that it has successfully synchronized. But the files I have added from other computers are not in my Ubuntu One folder.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `seahorse` (“Passwords and Encryption Keys” in the applications menu), look for the `Ubuntu One` key, and delete it. That should kick off the re-authentication from the client.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I was so focused on a "change" option to not think of such a simple workaround.

Comment: What could you do on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

In Preferences → Ubuntu One, choose the option "**I have an account**". It should work.

Comment: This only works before an account is set up on the machine. After I have connected before, I don't even see such an option. There is a "manage account" option, but it opens a browser and takes me to the login page for the web interface.

Comment: Weird, cause in my case i see this option.

Comment: I updated the question to show what I see when I open it.

Comment: hmmm its look really different from my panel. Ubuntu One Web interface have an option to change his password access. But it doesnt means the client have broken their connections to service. So the problem i think its not the password.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System Settings** **-> Ubuntu One** and click on **Sign In** and sign in with your new credentials.